# Textbox_AfterUpdate not working with another control

Tags: ms-access, vba

Why I can't change value of another control in access form in afterupdate function?

```
    Private Sub cNPSrate_AfterUpdate() 'Form_new_opinion_in!
If Not IsNull(cNPSRate) Then
    Select Case cNPSRate
        Case 1 To 6
            cNPSRate.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0) And cSegmentNPS.Text = "KRYTYK"
        Case 7 To 8
            cNPSRate.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0) And cSegmentNPS.Text = "NEUTRALNY"
        Case 9 To 10
            cNPSRate.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0) And cSegmentNPS.Text = "PROMOTOR"
    End Select
Else
cNPSRate.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) And cSegmentNPS.Text = Null
End If
End Sub
```

The code works if I remove `And cSegmentNPS.Text`. Can't I use another control in this function or I make some mistake?

cNPSRate and cSegmentNPS are TEXTBOXes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A text box's `.Text` property is only available when that text box has focus.  At any other time, use its `.Value` property instead.

I would also put each action on its own line instead of combining them with `And` on one line.

So I suggest you revise your code to follow this pattern ...

```vb
cNPSRate.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
cSegmentNPS.Value = "KRYTYK"
```